# calling c functions in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, file, mixing

Hi I am trying to use some pure C library in an iOS app, however I have no clue how to call and pass the parameters. Here are 2 functions, Node is a struct:

```
Node *parse(FILE *f);
void add_subnode(Node *t, Node *parent);
```

Can someone show me some sample code how to do it? Or point out to me some good books on this topic.

Thanks
Ray

Comment: You call and pass the parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call C functions like this:

```
Node *node = parse(f); // node will hold return value

add_subnode(t, parent);
```

Comment: wow, I feel so stupid. However I have another stupid question, how do I get a file handle? Say I have a tree.txt file in the main bundle, how do I get the C style file handle?

Comment: FILE *f = fopen("tree.txt", "r");

Comment: This should work - `FILE *f = fopen([[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"tree" ofType: @"txt"] UTF8String], "r");`

Comment: thank you sir, you are my savior.